# Ionic framework vs Google calendar api

Tags: ionic-framework, google-calendar-api

I am using Ionic framework to create an app like Meeting room booking for an organization.I am new to Ionic framework.
I need you guys to help in the following thinks
1).Oauth for Google signin
2)access Google calendar by send request with access token
3)need to get the JSON response for request.
4)and also,Important think is need to get the resource calendar (rooms,Projectors etc.,)

Please guide me how can i do that with Ionic framework.Still now I did not get any good tutorials.

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: I have business google app account.I need to a good tutorial for google signin and google calendar(list events,add events,list calendar and list resource calendar).I am decide to go with ionic framework.Please help me in this..

Comment: Please give me some good tutorial link regarding this

Answer (score 2):

@arun, I have developed a small hybrid app using ionic2 and integrated google calendar in the app. You can see a quick demo of the app @ [Google calendar in Ionic 2 app demo on android device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSwbBQTiYaU).
If this is what you are looking for, I believe the things you mentioned in the question which is google oauth login, accessing calendar and sending invites are covered. I am not sure whether you are developing using Ionic2. If yes please see the demo video and detailed steps.
[Demo and steps to integrate google calendar in the Ionic 2 app](http://nishanthkabra.com/ionic2GoogleCalandar.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Ionic framework** is integration of AngularJS which is best framework for cross platform. Which has large support of **ngCordova plugins**.

I have some links for you

1. For Google oAuth - http://blog.ionic.io/oauth-ionic-ngcordova/
2. For Google calender - http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/09/18/integrating-the-calendar-into-your-ionic-app

You can refer Intel@XDK is one of the best tool. I used it to develop cross development app wich supports multiple frameworks with IONIC.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for ages to integrate data from the google calendar into Ionic without any luck.

I have now been able to integrate it into my ionic app through my backend in node.js, I advice you to do the same.

This is the code I used in my backend

```
let eventCategories = require('./event.model');

let fs = require('fs');
let readline = require('readline');
let google = require('googleapis');
let googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json
let SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
let TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
let TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json';


module.exports = {
  getEventCategories,  
  getEvents,
  setResponseStatus
};

function getEventCategories(){
  return eventCategories.find({});
}

function getEvents(calendarId) {
  return loadClientSecrets()
    .then(res => authorize(JSON.parse(res))
                    .then(response => listEvents(response, calendarId)))

}

function loadClientSecrets(){
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content){
      if (err){
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: '+ err);
        reject(err);
      }
      else fulfill(content);
    }) 
  })
}



/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 */
function authorize(credentials) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    let clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    let clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    let redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    let auth = new googleAuth();
    let oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        fulfill(getNewToken(oauth2Client));
      } else {
        oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
        fulfill(oauth2Client);
      }
    });
  })
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client) {
  new Promise (function (fulfill, reject){
    let authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    let rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
      rl.close();
      oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
          reject(err);
        }
        oauth2Client.credentials = token;
        storeToken(token);
        fulfill(oauth2Client);
      });
    });
  })
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 */
function listEvents(auth, calendarId) {
  return new Promise(function ( fulfill, reject){
    var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
    calendar.events.list({
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
      maxResults: 10,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime'
    }, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        reject(err);
      }
      var events = response.items;
      if (events.length == 0) {
        console.log('No upcoming events found.');
      } else {
        console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
          console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
        }
        // return events
        fulfill(events)
      }
    });
  })

  function setResponseStatus(){

  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with node.js. How you use this code to get the data in the app?

Comment: This is just a full copy of my events controller, I could access these methods by making an api call (I'm no longer working on this project). 
Not sure what you are asking exactly, I'm still very novice so I'm not sure if I can help you any further